# Android - remove key/alias from keystore

Tags: java, android, android-keystore

I have keystore named **keystore.jks** and accidently **two keys** are added to it. I have to make a signed apk using **key2**. Because I have already uploaded an apk using **key2**, and I want to remove **Key1** from **keystore.jks**.

Signed apk is generating by using **Key1** but I need to make it using **key2**.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should ask a detailed question whats happening in android studio when you try to build application and why you are trying to remove one of the alias form keystore file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's regular Java keystore and you manage it using `keytool` ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html)), so

```
keytool -delete -alias ALIAS -keystore KEYSTORE
```

and in general `keytool -delete -help`:

```
keytool -delete [OPTION]...

Deletes an entry

Options:

 -alias <alias>                  alias name of the entry to process
 -keystore <keystore>            keystore name
 -storepass <arg>                keystore password
 -storetype <storetype>          keystore type
 -providername <providername>    provider name
 -providerclass <providerclass>  provider class name
 -providerarg <arg>              provider argument
 -providerpath <pathlist>        provider classpath
 -v                              verbose output
 -protected                      password through protected mechanism
```

> Signed apk is generating by using Key1 but I need to make it using key2 .

But this can be changed in Android Studio - alias of key used to sign release builds is not hardcoded nor permanent.

Comment: The problem is when i am going to generate a signed apk it always give me an error **Cannot recover key**. So I was assuming that there would be an issue with the key alias (I was wrong).